# delphi exe and dll without build with runtime packages

Tags: delphi, dll, runtime, frame, bpl

For my last project i was using many frames in my delphi application ,so i dicided to create dlls and put them inside the dlls(ALL created in Delphi)

i have gone through many websites and came up with the code that works but for that example i have to compile both apps and dlls with **build with runtime packages** which means i have to distribute the bpls also. and if dont check build with runtime packages error is coming

this is the code i found

in exe

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
type
TGetTheFrame =Function( Owner: TComponent; TheParent: TWinControl ): TFrame; stdcall ;
 var
  GetTheFrame : TGetTheFrame;
begin
try
   GetTheFrame(application,TabSheet1).Free ;
except
end;
frm := GetTheFrame(application,TabSheet1) ;
dllHandle := LoadLibrary('project1.dll') ;
   if dllHandle <> 0 then
   begin
     GetTheFrame := GetProcAddress(dllHandle, 'GetTheFrame') ;
  frm := GetTheFrame(application,TabSheet1)   //call the function
    {   ShowMessage('error function not found') ;
     FreeLibrary(dllHandle) ; }
   end
   else
   begin
     ShowMessage('xxxx.dll not found / not loaded') ;
   end
```

in dll

```
Function  GetTheFrame( Owner: TComponent; TheParent: TWinControl ): TFrame; stdcall;
Begin
 Result := TFrame2.Create( Owner );

 Result.Parent := TheParent;
End;
```

thats all but i want this code to work without runtime packages

Comment: but i am sure code is good because it worked with runtimw=e packages

Comment: What's the purpose of that first `GetTheFrame` call? If it was meant to do anything other than randomly trash your memory, then you're using it wrong. The compiler should warn that you're using an uninitialized variable there.

Comment: See my answer in your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985256/how-to-use-delphi-dlls-without-enabling-build-with-runtime-packages I think this question is a duplicate.

Comment: yaa i used  that first GetTheFrame to free the mem ,it may be sometimes wrong but its not going to be a big problem

Comment: thats why i have used try except there

Comment: You've misunderstood. That first call is wrong for two reasons (and not just sometimes, but *always*). `GetTheFrame` is a local variable, so upon entry to `Button1Click`, it will not have a valid value. In particular, it will not refer to the DLL function. Even if it *did* refer to a valid function, it's not accomplishing anything. The only memory it would free is the very same memory that *it just allocated*. It's a pointless call because it's not freeing anything that wasn't allocated previously.

Comment: And furthermore, you're unloading the DLL right after you create an object. You mustn't do that. The object you created still needs the DLL to reside in memory, or else the object's code will go away. The object's memory also won't be managed anymore because it was managed by the DLL's copy of the memory manager, which has of course disappeared.

Comment: What do you think you are you acheiving by using DLL's in the first place?  You have to distribute the dll's anyways, you might as well include the frames in the exe itself and save yourself the hassle.

Comment: @Grandmaster, if the frames are in DLLs, then the DLLs can be updated separately from the main program, possibly without even having to shut it down. Think *plug-ins*.

Comment: @Rob, I'm also thinking 'DLL Hell'.  Unless he really needs to keep the app running during an update, something I doubt since its obviously a GUI app if its using TFrames, it'd be far safer and make deployment simpler to to just put everything into the exe.  I get the sense that he's solving a problem here that he really doesnt have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Too bad. That code won't work without run-time packages. (And *with* run-time packages, you should use `LoadPackage` instead of `LoadLibrary`.)

Without packages, each module of your program (the EXE and each DLL) has its own copy of the definition of all the standard classes, including `TFrame`, `TWinControl`, and even `TObject`. A `TWinControl` class from the EXE doesn't look like a `TWinControl` to the DLL.

Since you're sharing classes between modules, you need to make sure they all have the same definitions of those classes, and run-time packages is how you do that.

If you really won't use run-time packages, then you need to change the interface of your DLL so it doesn't share any Delphi object types. Instead of the `TWinControl` parent, pass the control's `Handle` property, or any other `HWnd` value to serve as the parent window. The DLL code will not be able to assume that there is a Delphi object for the parent anymore, and the EXE will not be able to assume that the control it receives is a Delphi object; they will be restricted to using the Windows API to manipulate window handles and send messages.

Comment: The handle can be passed as a parameter and returned as the result of a function from within the DLL.